# Install Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition Error 1311

Tags: visual-studio-2008

**After i download iso of visual studio 2008,i install it then show me "ENU: [2] ERROR:Error 1311.Source file not found: c:\users\cathy\appdata\local\temp\rar$ex15.392\cab1.cab.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
"
Actually i installed under the E disk,so this file above show me doesn't exist. Someone told me that i should Copy the contents of the C:\VS_2 folder into the C:\VS_1 folder. But where i can find these folders?**

Answer (score 2):

You can also copy the file from that folder(.iso) where all .cab files are placed to the `c:\users\rahul\appdata\local\temp\rar$ex15.392\` location it will work as it will get those files which are required to do setup

Answer (score 0):

c:\users\cathy\appdata\local\temp is probably your `%TEMP%` folder. Do you have unused space in the C disk? Otherwise, try setting your `%TEMP%` to somewhere else and running the installation again.